# f- строка в функии

Tags: python, функции, pandas

Имею  базовый список столбцов своего data, у каждого из них разное количество последователей, пример("R0_Производитель 1", "R0_Производитель 5", 'R0_Производитель 11", 'sigma_Производитель 1', sigma_Производитель 2'  и .тд)

```
 cols = ['R0', 'sigma', 'Vt', 'I', 'Io', 'SI', 'KTC', 'MF','MF_spec', 'MF_otosh', 'CSR_carb']
```

Задача: Найти средневзвешенное для каждого их них по формуле:

```
data[f'R0_Производитель {i}']/100*data[f'Производитель {i}']
пример
data["R0_Производитель 5"]/100*data["Производитель 5"]
```

Ниже код, который работает:

```
#'R0'
w=0
for i in range(1,65):
    if f'R0_Производитель {i}' in data.columns:
        w+= data[f'R0_Производитель {i}']/100*data[f'Производитель {i}']
    else:
        continue
    data[f'R0_AVER']=w
```

Так как столбцов много, хотел бы завернуть это в функцию, но не получается. Какие могут быть варианты? Можно и без f' строки, но как без нее не представляю. Спасибо

Comment: Как именно пробовали завернуть? Без f-строки - через метод format, например, см.: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html

Comment: f-строка, субъективно, лучшее, что сейчас есть для работ со строками.  Тут другие вопросы возникают: почему захардкоден `range(1,65)`, какие данные содержит `data` переменная (достаточно будет пары полей)?

Comment: @Dmitry,  в cols   столбцы с окончанием  Производитель {X}. Общий диапазон для всех них Производитель 1 - Производитель 65. Если для одного столбца может быть Производитель 1, то для другого столбца не факт, что он будет, поэтому идет проверка на  if  in data.columns:

Comment: возможно это решается без циклов - векторным способом... Но для того чтобы можно было попробовать, нужно иметь примеры входных данных в воспроизводимом виде и ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def added_col(X):
    w=0
    for i in range(1,65):
        if '{}'.format(X)+'{}'.format(i) in data.columns:
            w+= data['{}'.format(X)+'{}'.format(i)]/100*data[f'Производитель {i}']
        else:
            continue
    data[X+'_Aver']=aw
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]